# On Spinner item selection, editText value is showing as empty. Happening only with Samsung Tab4 having Android version 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

- As soon as i click on Spinner item , editText value is showing as empty.
- This was happening only with Samsung Tab4 having Android version 4.4.2.
- Implemented "setOnItemSelectedListener" and in "onItemSelected" i can able to print EditText value as well, still showing empty in display but getText is giving me the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ho, found that dynamically setting text color is matching with background color. So, textview having values but not able to see that.